# Change day range excel after entering month name excel

Tags: excel

I need to know if there is a way to change the whole 'day' range after entering a specific month name in a cell.

For example

Enter month: January

Enter year : 2018

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZu1F.png)

Now when I enter February, the day range (mon,tue,wed...) changes automatically with accordance to 1st February till the end of the month.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure what you actually want here.  The `EOMONTH` function could come in handy to generate the date range for each month.

Comment: Hello Tim,

Got the solution below from Mr. Naveed.
Thanks for the response though. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use Date Functions and Custom Cell Date Formatting to display day name.

use this sheet

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OJIYvLnAi5_HCmZqCBpfSHiCE9fUGFbT/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm Naveed sb.:)